# Using angular material colors in my own components

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

If I want to style an element that is not a material 2 component, with the colors defined in the theme, what is the standard way to do so ?

So say I've a `h1` tag in a component and I would like the color to be my `primary color`. I would like to be able to do things like this:

```
h1{
  color: $color-primary; 
}
```

At the moment I have a theme.scss and styles.scss

**theme.scss**:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
$color-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$color-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A400, A200, A500);
$color-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$theme: mat-light-theme($color-primary, $color-accent, $color-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

I could import `theme.scss` in my `component.scss`, however they [state not to do so](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md#defining-a-custom-theme):

> Imports the mat-core() sass mixin. This includes all common styles
>   that are used by multiple components. This should only be included
>   once in your application. If this mixin is included multiple times,
>   your application will end up with multiple copies of these common
>   styles.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be solved by splitting your custom theme into multiple files.  For example, I have a `_mat-colors.scss` and `_mat-theme.scss`.  `_mat-colors` includes the three color variables needed; `_mat-theme` uses `_mat-colors` and is where I define my palettes and include mat-core.  You could then have a _variables or _colors file and use it as so:

```
@import '@angular/material/theming';
@import './mat-colors';

$color-red: mat-color($my-warn-palette);
```

You could then use `$color-red` or any other that you define as needed.

Comment: If you are importing `mat-colors` in a lot of component then you are also importing `mat-core` since `mat-colors` itself import it. As I said they said not to do that in their doc. So unless I miss something, I think this goes against their advice.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're correct @Ced.  Instead of using `@mat-core()` in `_mat-theme`, I think you can just call it in your main SASS file.  Or am I mistaken or have I misunderstood something?